# Async Task Timeout?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

There is a very common task I face again. I have already solved this a couple of times, but now I am looking for a more "**elegant**" way - can you deliver some input?

*Situation:*
I have a Method which I would like to run "semi async". In other words: Start it and wait a given time x. If the method is not finished by then ("timed out"), I want to continue my code with some cleanup procedures.

*Solutions so far:*

1. Use an AutoResetEvent (or
   ManualResetEvent) combined with an
   annonymus method using
   .WaitOne(x).
2. Use a Thread/BackgroundWorker
   combined with a Timer. If the timer
   hits its handler before the thread stops it, the therad is timed out.

Both appraochs work fine but I imagine there is a better way with 4.0.

Suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronously wait for Task<T> to complete with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does [`Task.Wait(Timeout)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606.aspx) from the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) do what you want? (You may wish to combine this with cancellation tokens to cancel the task after the timeout occurs.)