# Capturing Exceptions on async operations

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm reading up more about async here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx

Going through this example:

```
Task<bool> [] recommendations = …;
while(recommendations.Count > 0)
{ 
    Task<bool> recommendation = await Task.WhenAny(recommendations);    
    try
    {
        if (await recommendation) BuyStock(symbol);
        break;
    }
    catch(WebException exc)
    {
        recommendations.Remove(recommendation);
    }
}
```

I wonder, if I'm already performing await on `Task.WhenAny` why do I need to await again inside of the try block?

If I already did this: `Task<bool> recommendation = await Task.WhenAny(recommendations);`
Why do this: `if (await recommendation) BuyStock(symbol);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first `await` exists to asynchronously wait for the first task to complete (i.e. `recommendation`).
The second `await` is only there to extract the actual result out of the already completed task, and throw exceptions stored in the task. (*it's important to remember that awaiting a completed task is optimized and will execute synchronously*).

A different option to get the result would be using `Task<T>.Result`, however it differs in the way it handles exceptions. `await` would throw the actual exception (e.g `WebException`) while `Task<T>.Result` would throw an `AggregateException` containing the actual exception inside.

```
Task<bool> [] recommendations = …;
while(recommendations.Count > 0)
{ 
    Task<bool> recommendation = await Task.WhenAny(recommendations);    
    try
    {
        if (recommendation.Result) 
        {
            BuyStock(symbol);
        }
        break;
    }
    catch(AggregateException exc)
    {
        exc = exc.Flatten();
        if (exc.InnerExceptions[0] is WebException)
        {
            recommendations.Remove(recommendation);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**Clearly awaiting the task is simpler and so it's the recommended way of retrieving a result out of a task.**

Comment: This would throw an `AggregateException`, not a `WebException`, if the `Task` is faulted as a result of a `WebException`.

Comment: @Servy clarified that.

Comment: You've now mentioned that there is a difference, but you have still broken the code as a result of your change, because you have changed the error handling semantics in a way the code doesn't support.  The crux of your answer, that you can just change the code to use `Result`, is inherently wrong, because by making that change you broke the code.  There's a *very good reason* that the author of this code used `await` here.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't recommending using that code, it was part of the answer to "why use `await`?". I clarified that as well.

Comment: You asserted it gave the exact same behavior, but it didn't, because you broke the code.  Now all that's left of your answer is the remnants of your incorrect answer, which is, by your own admission, clearly not useful at all.

Comment: @Servy The assertion was removed. That was the clarification. And I disagree it wasn't useful. The question was "Why is that code using `await`?" and the answer always explained why.

Comment: No, it didn't, because the whole point of using `await` here is that it *doesn't* just get the result out.  It gets the result out *with a particular set of error handling semantics* that are vital to the function of the method.  And breaking the code in such a wait that it won't work, but it won't work in subtle and hard to debug ways is about as un-useful as an answer can get.  At this point pretty much the only useful content in your answer is the stuff that I told you needed to be in your answer, with most of the rest being *actively harmful*.

Comment: @Servy The question is basically why is there an extra `await` on top of the `await Task.WhenAny(...)` and the answer is to get out a result. It's true that it matters in what way that is done, and I'm glad you pointed that bug out. But even without the comparison with `Task<T>.Result` this post answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 5):

The use of `await` here creates the desired error handling semantics.  If he used `Result` instead of `await` then the `AggregateException` would be rethrown directly; when using `await` the first exception within the `AggregateException` is pulled out an *that* exception is re-thrown.  Clear the author of this code wanted the `WebException` to be thrown, rather than an `AggregateException` that he would need to manually unwrap.

Could he have used another approach, sure.  This was simply the approach that the author of the code preferred, as it allows him to write the code more like traditional synchronous code rather than radically changing the style of the code.

Answer (score 4):

You're right. It is not necessary. You could replace it with

```
if (recommendation.Result) 
    BuyStock(symbol);
```

Also note that `await` will not await(will not set continuation) when completed task is given. It will just execute synchronously in that case as a optimization. I guess author leverages that optimization.

If you ask why author wrote that way, May be consistency? only he knows!.

Answer (score 1):

> If I already did this: Task recommendation = await Task.WhenAny(recommendations); Why do this: if (await recommendation) BuyStock(symbol);

Because `Task.WhenAny` returns a `Task<Task<bool>>` and you want to unwrap the  outter `Task` to retrieve the resulting bool. You could do the same by accessing the `Task.Result` property of the returned `Task`

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have pointed out that you have to `await` the task returned by `await Task.WhenAll` to unwrap the return value (alternatively, you can use the `Result` property).

However, you can also get rid of your try/catch (and it's a good thing to avoid catching unnecessary exception)

```
Task<bool> recommendation = await Task.WhenAny(recommendations);    
if(!recommendation.IsFaulted)
{
    if (await recommendation) BuyStock(symbol);
    break;
}
else
{
    if(recommendation.Exception.InnerExceptions[0] is WebException)
    {
        recommendations.Remove(recommendation);
    }
    else
    {
        throw recommendation.Exception.InnerExceptions[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that when task is faulted `WhenAny` doesn't throw exception?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : perfectly sure. `WhenAny`returns a Task whose result is the firs Task that completed. A Task is completed if either it is successful or it is faulted. If a Task faults, `WhenAny`succeeds ans it gives you the first completed Task (i.e. the faulted one).

Comment: Wouldn't `recommendation.Exception` contain an `AggregateException`?

Comment: @I3arnon : you're right. I have updated mys answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Because [`Task.WhenAny<TResult>(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> tasks)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160383(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `Task<Task<TResult>>`. The outer task (the one created by the `Task.WhenAny` call) will complete when any of the tasks passed to it completes with the completed task as a result.