# Async Task.WhenAll with timeout - issue with completed tasks accumulating

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have created the following in order to execute multiple async tasks with a timeout. I was looking for something that will allow extracting results from the tasks - taking only those that beat the timeout, regardless if the rest of tasks failed to do so (simplified):

```
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0);

Task<Task>[] tasksOfTasks =
{
    Task.WhenAny(SomeTaskAsync("a"), Task.Delay(timeout)),
    Task.WhenAny(SomeTaskAsync("b"), Task.Delay(timeout)),
    Task.WhenAny(SomeTaskAsync("c"), Task.Delay(timeout))
};

Task[] completedTasks = await Task.WhenAll(tasksOfTasks);

List<MyResult> = completedTasks.OfType<Task<MyResult>>().Select(task => task.Result).ToList();
```

I have implemented this in a non-static class in the (Web API) server.

This worked well on the first call, however additional calls caused `completedTasks` to strangely accumulate tasks from previous calls to the server (as shown by the debugger). On the second call there were 6 completed tasks, on the third call 9 and so on.

**My questions:**

1. Any idea why is that?
   I assume it's because the previous tasks weren't cancelled however this code is in a new instance of a class!
2. Any idea how to avoid this accumulation?

**PS:** See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25595813/145599) question.

Comment: I have edited the other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716156/how-to-multiple-async-tasks-with-timeout-and-cancellation. Please read both carefully and you'll find that these are two different questions (+ with different code segments).

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't use my [psychic debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/01/28/psychic-debugging-of-async-methods.aspx) to understand why your code "caused `completedTasks` to strangely accumulate tasks from previous calls" but it does probably expose some of your misunderstandings.

Here's a working example based on your code (using `string` instead of `MyResult`):

```
Task<string> timeoutTask = 
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).ContinueWith(_ => string.Empty);

Task<Task<string>>[] tasksOfTasks =
{
    Task.WhenAny(SomeTaskAsync("a"), timeoutTask),
    Task.WhenAny(SomeTaskAsync("b"), timeoutTask),
    Task.WhenAny(SomeTaskAsync("c"), timeoutTask)
};
Task<string>[] completedTasks = await Task.WhenAll(tasksOfTasks);

List<string> results = completedTasks.Where(task => task != timeoutTask).
    Select(task => task.Result).ToList();
```

So, what's different:

- I'm using the same timeout task for all `WhenAny` calls. There's no need to use more, and they could complete in slightly different times.
- I make the timeout task return a value, so it's actually a `Task<string>` and not a `Task`.
- That makes each `WhenAny` call also return a `Task<string>` (and `tasksOfTasks` be `Task<Task<string>>[]`) which would make it possible to actually return a result out of these tasks.
- After `await`ing we need to filter out `WhenAny` calls that returned our timeout task, because there would be no result there (only `string.Empty`) using `completedTasks.Where(task => task != timeoutTask)`.

**P.S** : I've also [answered that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25733275/885318) and I would (*surprisingly*) recommend you use my solution.

---

**Note:** Using the `Task.Result` property [isn't advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25624426/885318). You should `await` it instead (**even when you know it's already completed**)

Comment: Thanks. I ran many tests and realized that when I initialize `tasksOfTasks` using an initializer as above, everything went well, but when I create the collection dynamically (e.g. by using a LINQ query into an `IEnumerable<Task<MyResult>>`) - which I need to do, tasks started to accumulate again. The sad thing is, when I tried your example above initialized dynamically, it still went fine, which means it might be other complexity in my code (which of course is more complex than what I've shown here).