# How to - Multiple Async tasks with timeout and cancellation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timeout, task, .net-4.5

I would like to fire several tasks while setting a timeout on them. The idea is to gather the results from the tasks that beat the clock, and cancel (or even just ignore) the other tasks.

I tried using extension methods WithCancellation as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25684549/145599), however throwing an exception caused WhenAll to return and supply no results.

Here's what I tried, but I'm opened to other directions as well (note however that I need to use await rather than Task.Run since I need the httpContext in the Tasks):

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

IEnumerable<Task<MyResults>> tasks = 
            from url in urls
            select taskAsync(url).WithCancellation(cts.Token);

Task<MyResults>[] excutedTasks = null;

MyResults[] res = null;
try
{
    // Execute the query and start the searches:
    excutedTasks = tasks.ToArray();

    res = await Task.WhenAll(excutedTasks);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    if (excutedTasks != null)
    {
        foreach (Task<MyResults> faulted in excutedTasks.Where(t => t.IsFaulted))
        {
            // work with faulted and faulted.Exception
        }
    }
}

// work with res
```

**EDIT:**
Following @Servy's answer below, this is the implementation I went with:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

IEnumerable<Task<MyResults>> tasks = 
            from url in urls
            select taskAsync(url).WithCancellation(cts.Token);

// Execute the query and start the searches:
Task<MyResults>[] excutedTasks = tasks.ToArray();

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(excutedTasks);
}
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // Do nothing - we expect this if a timeout has occurred
}

IEnumerable<Task<MyResults>> completedTasks = excutedTasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);

var results = new List<MyResults>();
completedTasks.ForEach(async t => results.Add(await t));
```

Comment: what does `taskAsync` do?

Comment: In my case they retrieve info using an httpClient however I think any async task will do (The one you supplied below should do just fine). The point is that taskAsync doesn't receive a cancellation token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the tasks fail to complete you are correct that `WhenAll` doesn't return the results of any that *did* complete, it just wraps an aggregate exception of all of the failures.  Fortunately, you have the original collection of tasks, so you can get the results that completed successfully from there.

```
var completedTasks = excutedTasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
```

Just use that instead of `res`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code and it worked just fine, except the cancelled tasks are in not in a Faulted state, but rather in the Cancelled. So if you want to process the cancelled tasks use `t.IsCanceled` instead. The non cancelled tasks ran to completion. Here is the code I used:

```
    public static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var urls = new List<string> {"url1", "url2", "url3", "url4", "url5", "url6"};

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        IEnumerable<Task<MyResults>> tasks =
            from url in urls
            select taskAsync(url).WithCancellation(cts.Token);

        Task<MyResults>[] excutedTasks = null;

        MyResults[] res = null;
        try
        {
            // Execute the query and start the searches:
            excutedTasks = tasks.ToArray();

            res = await Task.WhenAll(excutedTasks);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            if (excutedTasks != null)
            {
                foreach (Task<MyResults> faulted in excutedTasks.Where(t => t.IsFaulted))
                {
                    // work with faulted and faulted.Exception
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static async Task<MyResults> taskAsync(string url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start " + url);
        var random = new Random();
        var delay = random.Next(10);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay));

        Console.WriteLine("End " + url);

        return new MyResults();
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for running it! It is true that tasks run to completion, however once a cancellation occurred, WhenAll returns and in `res` I get no results. I was expecting to find there the results of the tasks that were completed before the time out. I added some code (between the `//////////////` to show this).

Comment: (I edited my original question to emphasize this 'Results' part).