# How to timout on this task

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, timeout, task

I am calling a third party library API's **Run** method as follows

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ThirdPartLibraryAPI.Run());
```

I would like to setup some timeout on this in case this API takes too long. How can I do that?

Comment: Create another task using Task.Delay() and then use Task.WhenAny() to wait on only the first task to complete.
More at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846615/async-task-whenall-with-timeout

Comment: I am not sure how that applies in this case as I just have one task. May be if you can post an answer with code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code snippet:

```
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(1500);
        //using .ContinueWith(t => /*stuff to do on timeout*/);
        //will cause the code to execute even if the timeout did not happen.
        //remember that this task keeps running. we are just not waiting for it
        //in case the worker task finishes first.

        var workerTask = Task.Run(() => { ThirdPartLibraryAPI.Run() });
        var taskThatCompletedFirst = await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, workerTask);

        //stuff to do on timeout can be done here
        //if (taskThatCompletedFirst == timeoutTask)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this snippet

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ThirdPartLibraryAPI.Run());
Task.WaitAny(t, miliseconds);
```

Comment: how am i going to know that task completed vs timeout here?

Comment: Plus WaitAny is a blocking call.