# How do I take a Task<T> and put a timeout on it?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

My other question basically needed this so I thought I would share my generic solution here.

I had trouble with HttpClient Tasks for web requests basically never completing; so the program or thread hangs. I needed a simple way to add a timeout to a task, so that it returns normally or returns cancelled if the timeout expires first.

Some alternative approaches can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx

Comment: I've voted to close because it's not good practice to post and answer your own question. Please consider moving this to codereview.stackexchange.com if your intent was to show off a clever code fragment and get feedback on it

Comment: AZ have you posted a question recently? It offers you to "share your knowledge" by answering your own question.

Comment: @AZ. What makes you think it's not good practice to post and answer your own question? There's even an "Answer your own question" checkbox in the "Ask Question" form.

Comment: @AZ: If you think it is bad practice you should probably discuss your viewpoint on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question). The current implementation actually [supports answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz).

Comment: Or you can use a simple solution like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11191070/1659828

Comment: There is a difference between asking something, not getting a good reply and coming back later after more research to answer your own question and posting the question and the answer at the same time. I've voted to close because i believe that codereview.stackexchange might be a better place for this kind of stuff. Feel free to not back my vote if you feel different.

Comment: And if you read Honza's comment it appears this was actually asked and answered before. Another reason to close it

Comment: @AZ. but he's not asking for a code review, he's sharing knowledge. He claims he found a solution to a common problem, to which there was no satisfactory response on stack overflow. Whether the claim is valid or not, that's a different question.

Comment: I think you should explain in more detail what the question actually is. Without it, the answer is pretty much useless.

Comment: Did you consider setting [HttpClient.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx)? Seems like that'd be a whole lot easier.

Comment: Jim, of course I did. I think it just calls Abort on an HttpWebRequest object.

Comment: I have no idea why this question is "on hold" but it was pretty successful while it lasted. Thanks Servy for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You technically can't take a task and force it to be canceled after some period of time.  The best that you can do is create a new task that will be marked as canceled after the given period of time, or will be completed when the other task is if it finishes in time.

A key point to note is that the operation timing out doesn't stop the task from continuing on with it's work, it just fires off all continuations of this new task "early" if the timeout is reached.

Doing this is pretty trivial, thanks to the use of `CancellationToken`:

```
var newTask = task.ContinueWith(t => { }
    , new CancellationTokenSource(timeoutTime).Token);
```

We can combine this patter with `WhenAny` to easily ensure that any exceptions are properly propagated through to the continuation.  A copy for tasks with/without a result is also needed:

```
public static Task WithTimeout(Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var delay = task.ContinueWith(t => { }
        , new CancellationTokenSource(timeout).Token);
    return Task.WhenAny(task, delay).Unwrap();
}
public static Task<T> WithTimeout<T>(Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var delay = task.ContinueWith(t => t.Result
        , new CancellationTokenSource(timeout).Token);
    return Task.WhenAny(task, delay).Unwrap();
}
```

Comment: But the continuewith only occurs if the underlying task is completed! I don't think that this guarantees completion. Unless I'm wrong about that...

Comment: ContinueWith: "The returned Task will not be scheduled for execution until the current task has completed, whether it completes due to running to completion successfully, faulting due to an unhandled exception, or exiting out early due to being canceled." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Elliot It won't complete normally until the underlying task is completed.  It will be cancelled if the cancellation token indicates that it should be cancelled.  That's the whole *point* of a cancellation token.  If a cancellation token being marked as canceled never cancelled a task there would be no point in ever passing one in.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't timeout the underlying task so it's not a solution.

Comment: @Elliot Your solution doesn't either.  It's *impossible* to solve that in the general case, as I said in response to your solution.  This answer does what your answer does, but in one line of code instead of 45.  They are functionally identical though.

Comment: Sorry Servy, I know that the unresizeable box is annoying but you should read my solution again.

Comment: @Elliot I have.  You create a TCS, and if the task completes normally, is cancelled on it's own, or throws an exception, you propagate it's state, if the given time passes then you cancel the TCS.  This is functionally doing the same thing.  If you wanted, you could throw this into a method to shorten it further, but it's so short as it is I don't know if I'd even bother.  What gives you the impression that your method in any way cancels the underlying task when the timeout is reached?  It doesn't.

Comment: I didn't mean that it cancels the underlying; a never ending task will still be never ending. What I needed was for this situation not to block the program when the task is awaited. A continuewith only runs (or cancels) if the underlying completes. It's not the same.

Comment: @Elliot No, that's not true.  The task resulting from the continuation will be marked as cancelled as soon as the cancellation token says it is canceled, even if the task is it a continuation of has not finished yet.

Comment: Thanks Servy, I need to test it out before ticking your answer.

Comment: Thanks again; I wouldn't have guessed that a continuation could complete before its underlying. I think you should post your answer here too:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout

Comment: @Elliot If you found that question why post your own?  In any case, the top answer there is fine.

Comment: Basically that method would have had async and await keywords and would have returned Task<Task<T>>. I saw that method in the article i linked to at the top. The Cancellation for contiuations must have been added since that article I guess.

Comment: @Elliot Continuations have supported cancellation since the beginning.  It's not new.  As I said in my earlier comment, there'd be no point in accepting them in the first place unless they acted this way; they'd never do anything useful otherwise.

Comment: ..but as you have showed me there is the Unwrap method...

Comment: Note!!!!!! This sample code is not correct. It has a racing issue here. Considering this case, the original task met an exception, the delay task is continued from the original task. The Task.WhenAny may have a racing case that the delay task is returned first, and then it will swallow the exception in the original task.

Consider to use Task.Delay for the timeout check, and further check the returned task of Task.WhenAny() method. Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout

Comment: @Yingqin If the delay finishes before the original task faults then the expected behavior is to return the cancelled task.  Yes, there is a race condition in which the main task races with the timer to see if it finishes before or after the delay, but that's inherent to the operation being requested, and it's not *possible* to eliminate it.  The answer you've linked has exactly the same behavior.  If the delay finishes before the original task, you get a canceled task, not the result of the original task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CancellationTokenSource when the timeout come:

```
var DefualtTimeout = 5000;
var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

var taskWithTimeOut = Task.Factory.StartNew( t =>
                           {
                              var token = (CancellationToken)t;
                              while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                              {
                                 // Here your work
                              }
                              token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                           }, cancelToken.Token, cancelToken.Token);
```

---

Approach 1:

```
   if (!taskWithTimeOut.Wait(DefualtTimeout, cancelToken.Token)) 
      {
         cancelToken.Cancel();
      }
```

---

Approach 2:

```
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => taskWithTimeOut.IsCompleted, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, DefualtTimeout ));
```

---

Approach 3:

You can make the method async and before the task write `await taskWithTimeOut.Wait..`  in this way the UI will not blocked.