# Why does my task not cancel?

Tags: c#, task, libcurl

I'm running a process that periodically Curls to a list of URLs to test out performance to those websites. My main program is basically a do...sleep...while loop that calls a function, runTest() every N seconds, with a keyboard interrupt to kill it off. Pared down to the basics, my code is as follows:

```
public void runTest()
{
   if(isRunning)
   {
      return; //Plus some logging that one or more of the tests hasn't completed
   }
   try {
       isRunning = true;
       Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
       CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(httpTimeoutValueMs * 2);
       foreach (var url in urls)
            taskList.Add(doAsyncCurls(url, cts))
       List<CurlResults> listOfResults = Task.WhenAll(taskList.Select(x => x)).Result.ToList();
       taskList.Clear();
  }
  catch {/*Some exception handling code*/}
  finally { 
    isRunning = false; 
    Curl.GlobalCleanup();
  }
}
private static async Task<CurlResults> doAsyncCurls(string url, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    try
    {
      /*Initiate a Curl using libCurl*/
      Easy easy = new Easy();
      easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, url);
      easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 0); //Disables DNS cache
      easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, httpTimeoutValueMs / 1000); //20sec timeout

      Task t = new Task(() => easy.Perform(), cts.Token);
      t.Start();
      await t;
      return new CurlResults(/*valid results parameters*/);
    } 
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    { /*Cancellation token invoked*/
        return new CurlResults(/*Invalid results parameters*/);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { /*Other exception handling*/ 
        return new CurlResults(/*Invalid results parameters*/);
    }
```

The "doAsyncCurl" function does what it says on the tin, setting an http timeout value to half that of the cancellation token, so that the HTTP request should evaporate before the cancellation token is invoked, and generate a negative result. I added the cancellation token to try and deal with my problem as below.

I leave this running for ages - to start with, everything works well, but eventually (hundreds, if not more iterations through the periodic runTest() invocation) it seems that one of the tasks gets stuck and the cancellation token isn't invoked, and the curl testing process is effectively stuck.

Apart from picking up which URL(s) are problematic (and they're all valid ones), what can be done to diagnose what's going wrong? Or have I constructed my parallel Curls completely wrongly to start with? (I appreciate that I could instantiate new Curls to URLs that have finished from the previous round and leave the hung one to dangle, rather than waiting for them all to finish before kicking off a new batch, but I'm not bothered about that efficiency gain).

Comment: Passing a reference to the token doesn't imply automatic task cancellation in the body of the task.  You still need to periodically check it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712939/cancellation-token-in-task-constructor-why?rq=1

Comment: OK - so I've ballsed up my cancellation token implementation, but I'm also confused as to why the Curl isn't timing out, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatism in cancellation. You have to check for the cancellation status and end your execution or invoke `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` to perform the cancellation. The `CancellationToken` will tell you *if* cancellation is requested; the cancellation *itself* has to be done by you.

The following line is your problem:

```
Task t = new Task(() => easy.Perform(), cts.Token);
```

You are passing the token to the task constructor. That will help you if your cancellation occurs *before* the task is started. Once the task is started, the executed method is responsible for cancellation. `easy.Perform()` does not know about your cancellation token and therefore will never be able to determine if cancellation is requested. Hence, it will run to its end.

You need to regularly check your cancellation token during task execution to achieve what you want.

Comment: should/could I instead use, after this line, a "t.wait(timoutMs)" rather than bothering with the token and using "await t"?

Comment: Yes, you could, but that won't end your task. It will still run its turn to the end.

Comment: @JetSetJim If you did that then the code wouldn't be asynchronous.  You could construct a new task that would.  You can use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20248663/1159478) to create a task that will finish when the cancellation token is cancelled, but that won't stop the operation from continuing on to do...whatever it wants to do, if that's enough for you.

Comment: @Sefe - So would that mean that the easy.Perform() instantiated in the hung task would continue to exist until it completes? Might be an issue if it keeps hanging in subsequent calls as nothing would be tidying it up

Comment: If it throws an exception, it would fault the task and thereby end it. If you want to track executions that hang, you will have to track those executions yourself and act accordingly. The task framework itself doesn not offer you a way to kill tasks. You could figure out the thread a task is running and kill that thread, but that is a dirty solution and is not recommended.