# await hangs forever on socket ConnectAsync when Android is disconnected

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

If I execute the following code on an Android device with no network connectivity, the await call will never complete nor will any exceptions be thrown by `ConnectAsync` even if `Close` or `Dispose`, etc. are invoked on the socket object (the catch handlers in this sample will never be reached, in other words):

```
            CancellationToken token = _tokenSource.Token;
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                using (token.Register(OnCancel))
                {
                    await _socket.ConnectAsync("176.222.222.222", 1234);
                }
            }
            catch(ObjectDisposedException)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
```

However, this is *not* the behavior on Windows or Linux: on those platforms, ConnectAsync will immediately toss a *"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10065): A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host."* exception if they're disconnected from any network, and if I choose to call either `Close` or `Dispose` on the socket object whilst it's attempting to connect when network is available, I'll get an exception about the I/O attempt being aborted. This is all expected behavior.

Is there any reason short of a bug in Mono that'd cause this Android-specific behavior? I have a working example here: https://github.com/kwende/MqttNetExampleIssues.

**Edit:**

It's possible my example isn't clear enough. Here is an example block of code using a timeout that's much simpler to read. The effect is the same, but perhaps this is a bit clearer. In the event of a timeout, the `Register` call should result in `OnCancel` being called, which should Close/Dispose of the socket. Doing so does nothing as far as continuation is concerned: the await never returns. I'm limited to button click events to show this off as I'm in Xamarin. The full code is available here: https://github.com/kwende/MqttNetExampleIssues/blob/main/Android/AndroidHang2/AndroidHang2/AndroidHang2/MainPage.xaml.cs. It can be downloaded and ran to show off the issue:

```
    private void OnCancel()
    {
        _socket?.Close(); 
        _socket?.Dispose();

        _socket = null; 
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
            {
                using(cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(OnCancel))
                {
                    _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                    try
                    {
                        await _socket.ConnectAsync("172.222.222.222", 1234);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        // if your network is off, the timeout will occur, OnCancel will be called,
                        // close and dispose will be called, but this will never get hit. 
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps not directly an answer to your question, but consider working around the problem using a timeout: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25500649/199364

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that there seems to be an actual hang, so it's a resource leak. Calling dispose/close on the socket doesn't actually seem to release all the resources. So, any sort of timeout/cancellation just leaves the await hanging.

Comment: Correct. That's the underlying issue. My GitHub repo shows that off. It _never returns_ and _no exception_ is thrown from ConnectAsync.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, it's worth noting: the synchronous version of Connect will fail as expected (exceptions will get tossed/caught), so it's strictly the async version that fails in the way I describe.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but nowhere do I see you **set a timeout** on that cancellationtoken. IMPORTANT: Not referring to any timeout on http, but on the cancellationtoken itself. As seen in answer on the SO post I linked.

Comment: You aren't blind, but it's part of running the app. There's a button click event that calls .Cancel() explicitly on the token source.

https://github.com/kwende/MqttNetExampleIssues/blob/5f21c585998a9489abce07956aaf8339da4f3fcb/Android/AndroidForeverHang/AndroidForeverHang/MainPage.xaml.cs#L139

If I tap that whilst the connect is hanging, no exception is ever thrown.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I updated my issue with a, hopefully, clearer example of what I'm encountering. Hopefully this makes it easier to understand what it is I'm reporting. Thanks.

Comment: Most comments removed above. Summary of private chat: Confirmed UI thread not blocked. Moved code to background thread just in case. Explicit cancel of task does not result in task cancelled exception, which it should. OP found a related open issue on github. OP created a new issue for this case.