# Timeout behaviour in HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() vs GetResponseAsync()

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, async-await

When I try the following code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 3; // a small value

var response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(response.ContentLength);
```

for a URL that I know it is going to take more than 3 millisecond to load (I put a `Thread.Sleep(110000)` in `Application_BeginRequest`) it works fine and throws a `WebException` as expected.

Problem is when I switch to async method:

```
var response = request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
```

or

```
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

This async version completely ignores any Timeout value, including `ReadWriteTimeout` and `ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime`

I couldn't find anything about Timeout in MSDN's `GetResponseAsync()` now I'm wondering if it is a bug in `GetResponseAsync()` or something is wrong in the way I use async here?

Comment: see answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout

Comment: Does it mean they intentionally ignore Timeout in all async APIs? I find that hard to believe. For example in this specific case this leaves the API user with no way to set different timeout values for different stages like ReadWriteTimeout/ContinueTimeout

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Timeout` does not apply to asynchronous `HttpWebRequest` requests. To quote [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Timeout property has no effect on asynchronous requests

I recommend you use `HttpClient` instead, which was designed with asynchronous requests in mind.

Comment: "The Timeout property has no effect on asynchronous requests **made with the BeginGetResponse or BeginGetRequestStream method.**": docs are not about GetResponseAsync, but answer is right anyway, because GetResponseAsync uses BeginGetResponse inside.

Answer (score 0):

Follow a solution to solve the problem.

```
await Task.Run(() => { 
  var varHttpResponse = varWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
});
```

Comment: This works, but you may now have a runaway open connection, and they can accumulate over time.

Comment: Fake async - this blocks.