# Avoid Application.DoEvents() in C#

Tags: c#, doevents

A lot of good programmers (including a lot of good members of Stackoverflow) are against using `Application.DoEvents()` whatever the circumstances are. Actually it is even supported with plenty of articles in the net, like [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx), [this famous debate on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents), ...

Though, I'm stuck in a case, where (I) think `DoEvents()` is the unique exit (lack of experience). That's enough as introduction, let's see some coding.

I have a 'serialPort' component to connect with a controller through serial communication, send command and wait for its response, that's all.

```
string response = "";
bool respFlag;

private string sendCommand(string command)
{
  respFlag = false;  //initialize respFlag

  serialPort1.Write(command);  // send the command

  Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew(); // start a timer
  while(true)
  {
    // break from the loop if receive a response
    if(respFlag) break;  

    // timeOut error if no response for more than 500msec
    if(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 500) break;

    // here comes the UGLY part
    Application.DoEvents(); 
  }

   return response;
}
```

in DataReceived method of my serialPort, I read the existing response and break the loop

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  response = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

  // set the flag to true to exit the infinite loop in sendCommand
  respFlag = true; 
}
```

It's not exactly like this, but this is a sample code that shows how I sned-receive via serial communication, would you kindly show me where am I forcing myself into this pitfall?

Comment: What version of .NET are you running?

Comment: You'll find that `goto` is supported. So too is `catch (Exception ex)`. It doesn't mean that you should use them. So don't use `Application.DoEvents()` - it is evil.

Comment: @Enigmativity, exactly man, I'm not debating use/don't use, I am seeking an alternative but can't find, that's why I asked here :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am on 4.5 , VS2012

Comment: @chouaib - Take a look at `async`/`await`, TPL, or Rx (Reactive Framework).

Comment: @Enigmativity: thank you so much I will consider them too as my next (to learn) topics, I appreciate your time and effort

Comment: @Enigmativity: I just notice this, can you please elaborate more on `dont use catch(exception ex)` ?

Comment: @chouaib - Catch-all exception handling hides bugs in code - they can make the code run, even when it should have failed, and then can cause errors elsewhere in your program - or even corrupt the run-time. They basically make your code buggy. You should always only catch exceptions that are exceptional and that you can actually handle properly.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I understand that it is not **NEVER** use `catch exception`, but use it **wisely** rather, example: In the accepted answer here I HAVE to catch the `TimeOutException`. is my understanding ok?

Comment: @chouaib - Absolutely catch things like `TimeOutException` - that is a truly exceptional event that you can handle. I can't think of any place where a plain `catch (Exception ex)` should be used, except maybe at the very top-level class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.5 it is really easy to do with async/await and a TaskCompletionSource and async/await.

```
TaskCompletionSource<string> resultTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
private async Task<string> SendCommandAsync(string command)
{
    serialPort1.Write(command);  // send the command

    var timeout = Task.Delay(500);

    //Wait for either the task to finish or the timeout to happen.
    var result = await Task.WhenAny(resultTcs.Task, timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);

    //Was the first task that finished the timeout task.
    if (result == timeout)
    {
        throw new TimeoutException(); //Or whatever you want done on timeout.
    }
    else
    {
        //This await is "free" because the task is already complete. 
        //We could have done ((Task<string>)result).Result but I 
        //don't like to use .Result in async code even if I know I won't block.
        return await (Task<string>)result;
    }
}
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var response = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    tcs.SetResult(response);

    //reset the task completion source for another call.
    resultTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
}
```

Comment: and this async method can be calld like `string str = SendCommandAsync("*****");` ? right?

Comment: It would be called like `string str = await SendCommandAsync("*****");`

Comment: thanks for the guidance, I will read more about async/await, meanwhile I will try your solution and report back to you

Comment: the line `return await (Task<string>)result;` is giving an error `Cannot convert from Task<Task> to Task<string>` !! any hints?

Comment: @chouaib: are you sure you have the `await` with the call to `Task.WhenAny()`? If you'd left that out, that would explain the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `async` I/O methods.  [Asynchronously wait for Task<T> to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout) is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the answer is to run that loop in a different thread and send a message to the UI when the response is available. This assumes you cant do async IO for some reason