# Random tasks from Task.Factory.StartNew never finishes

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, threadpool

I am using Async await with Task.Factory method.

```
public async Task<JobDto> ProcessJob(JobDto jobTask)
{
    try
    {
        var T = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            JobWorker jobWorker = new JobWorker();
            jobWorker.Execute(jobTask);
        });

        await T;
    }
```

This method I am calling inside a loop like this

```
for(int i=0; i < jobList.Count(); i++)
{
    tasks[i] = ProcessJob(jobList[i]);
}
```

What I notice is that new tasks opens up inside Process explorer and they also start working (based on log file). however out of 10 sometimes 8 or sometimes 7 finishes. Rest of them just never come back.

1. why would that be happening ?
2. Are they timing out ? Where can I set timeout for my tasks ?

**UPDATE**

Basically above, I would like each Task to start running as soon as they are called and wait for the response on AWAIT T keyword. I am assuming here that once they finish each of them will come back at Await T and do the next action. I am alraedy seeing this result for 7 out of 10 tasks but 3 of them are not coming back.

Thanks

Comment: how are you waiting for them? Are there any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Did you try `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` after your for loop? You are not waiting for your `tasks` to complete.

Comment: @Ned I am waiting by using await key word....

Comment: @ArghyaC I do not want to do WaitAll because than I will have to wait for all the tasks to finish before doing next action. I do not want ot block the call....basically I want each task to start running and do their thing right away. Once they are done than come back and report it to me on Await T word

Comment: You really [should not](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) be combining `await` with `TaskFactory.StartNew`, use `Task.Run(` instead.

Comment: Do you mean use await with Task.Run...I tried that and had similar result.

Comment: @Zeus I've added an answer with explanation, see if that helps.

Comment: My problem is closure variable i which is changing inside the loop...Jon skeet explained it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say what the issues is without the rest if the code, but you code can be simplified by making `ProcessJob` synchronous and then calling `Task.Run` with it.

```
public JobDto ProcessJob(JobDto jobTask)
{
    JobWorker jobWorker = new JobWorker();
    return jobWorker.Execute(jobTask);
}
```

Start tasks and wait for all tasks to finish. Prefer using `Task.Run` rather than `Task.Factory.StartNew` as it provides more favourable defaults for pushing work to the background. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

```
for(int i=0; i < jobList.Count(); i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => ProcessJob(jobList[i]));
}

try
{
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // handle exception
}
```

Comment: I do not want to block the call so I am not doing WhenAll...I am basically starting the Task but Task.Run and doing await

Answer (score 2):

First, let's make a reproducible version of your code. This is NOT the best way to achieve what you are doing, but to show you what is happening in your code!

I'll keep the code almost same as your code, except I'll use simple `int` rather than your `JobDto` and on completion of the job `Execute()` I'll write in a file that we can verify later. Here's the code

```
public class SomeMainClass
{
    public void StartProcessing()
    {
        var jobList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
        var tasks = new Task[10];
        //[1] start 10 jobs, one-by-one
        for (int i = 0; i < jobList.Count(); i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = ProcessJob(jobList[i]);
        }
        //[4] here we have 10 awaitable Task in tasks
        //[5] do all other unrelated operations
        Thread.Sleep(1500); //assume it works for 1.5 sec
        // Task.WaitAll(tasks); //[6] wait for tasks to complete
        // The PROCESS IS COMPLETE here
    }

    public async Task ProcessJob(int jobTask)
    {
        try
        {
            //[2] start job in a ThreadPool, Background thread
            var T = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                JobWorker jobWorker = new JobWorker();
                jobWorker.Execute(jobTask);
            });
            //[3] await here will keep context of calling thread
            await T; //... and release the calling thread
        }
        catch (Exception) { /*handle*/ }
    }
}

public class JobWorker
{
    static object locker = new object();
    const string _file = @"C:\YourDirectory\out.txt";
    public void Execute(int jobTask) //on complete, writes in file
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500); //let's assume does something for 0.5 sec
        lock(locker)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(_file, 
                Environment.NewLine + "Writing the value-" + jobTask);
        }
    }
}
```

After running just the `StartProcessing()`, this is what I get in the file

```
Writing the value-4
Writing the value-2
Writing the value-3
Writing the value-1
Writing the value-6
Writing the value-7
Writing the value-8
Writing the value-5
```

So, 8/10 jobs has completed. Obviously, every time you run this, the number and order might change. But, the point is, all the jobs did not complete!

Now, if I un-comment the step [6] `Task.WaitAll(tasks);`, this is what I get in my file

```
Writing the value-2
Writing the value-3
Writing the value-4
Writing the value-1
Writing the value-5
Writing the value-7
Writing the value-8
Writing the value-6
Writing the value-9
Writing the value-10
```

So, all my jobs completed here!

Why the code is behaving like this, is already explained in the code-comments. The main thing to note is, your tasks run in `ThreadPool` based `Background` threads. So, if you do not wait for them, they will be killed when the MAIN process ends and the main thread exits!!

If you still don't want to await the tasks there, you can return the list of tasks from this first method and `await` the tasks at the very end of the process, something like this

```
public Task[] StartProcessing()
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < jobList.Count(); i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = ProcessJob(jobList[i]);
    }
    ...
    return tasks;
}

//in the MAIN METHOD of your application/process
var tasks = new SomeMainClass().StartProcessing();
// do all other stuffs here, and just at the end of process
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Hope this clears all confusion.

Comment: Hi, Great explaination....my problem is if I do Task.Waitall than my loop will have to wait. This entire code is running inside windows service with timer so I do not want to block for all tasks to finish. This could be a problem in my design. Thoughts ??

Comment: ....looks like I am on a timer event so it recycles the old thread...this will cause my await tasks to get lost...correct ?

Comment: It'd be great if @StephenCleary could help here with better approach and/or explanation :)

Comment: @Zeus It's hard to comment without seeing your actual code, but the Tasks should complete given the calling thread doesn't exit or enough time. Check if it's possible to do something in the line of the alternative code given at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your code is swallowing exceptions.  I would add a `ContineWith` call to the end of the part of the code that starts the new task.  Something like this untested code:

```
var T = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            JobWorker jobWorker = new JobWorker();
            jobWorker.Execute(jobTask);
        }).ContinueWith(tsk =>
        {
            var flattenedException = tsk.Exception.Flatten();
            Console.Log("Exception! " + flattenedException);
            return true;
         });
        },TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);  //Only call if task is faulted
```

Another possibility is that something in one of the tasks is timing out (like you mentioned) or deadlocking.  To track down whether a timeout (or maybe deadlock) is the root cause, you could add some timeout logic (as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11191070/301703) SO answer):

```
int timeout = 1000; //set to something much greater than the time it should take your task to complete (at least for testing)
var task = TheMethodWhichWrapsYourAsyncLogic(cancellationToken);
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken)) == task)
{
    // Task completed within timeout.
    // Consider that the task may have faulted or been canceled.
    // We re-await the task so that any exceptions/cancellation is rethrown.
    await task;

}
else
{
    // timeout/cancellation logic
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx) on exception handling in the TPL on MSDN.