# Random Tasks of Task.Factory.StartNew don't start

Tags: c#, semaphore, multitasking

I need to have 5 tasks completed in parallel with max 2 executed at a time.
So, as soon as some task is finished, the next should be run - up until there are no tasks pending.

I'm using a [solution by L.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075029/have-a-set-of-tasks-with-only-x-running-at-a-time) which involves using semaphores for synchronization across tasks.

```
void LaunchTaskPool ()
    {
        SemaphoreSlim maxThreadSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2); //Max 2 tasks at a time.

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)                     //loop through 5 tasks to be assigned
        {
            maxThreadSemaphore.Wait();                  //Wait for the queue

            Console.WriteLine("Assigning work {0} ", i);

            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                DoWork(i.ToString());                   // assign tasks
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
                )
                .ContinueWith(
                (task) => maxThreadSemaphore.Release()  // step out of the queue
                );
        }

    }

    void DoWork(string workname)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine("--work {0} starts", workname);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("--work  {0} finishes", workname);

    }
```

The problem is that some random tasks would not even start. For example here Work 1 and 3 never started and Work 4 got run twice:

[image: Output]

I tried adding Task.WaitAll() as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887442/random-tasks-from-task-factory-startnew-never-finishes), but it didn't help.

thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Constantine.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using `Parallel.For()` for this instead; there's no need to reinvent the wheel! You can specify `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` when using `Parallel.For()`:

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Parallel.For(
                0, // Inclusive start
                5, // Exclusive end
                new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2},
                i => DoWork(i.ToString()));
        }

        static void DoWork(string workname)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine("--work {0} starts", workname);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("--work  {0} finishes", workname);

        }
    }
}
```

(Actually I just looked, and this is already in one of the other answers in the thread you linked - is there a reason you didn't want to use that solution? If not, I guess we should close this question as a duplicate...)

Anyway to answer your actual question:

[You are accessing a "modified closure" in the loop.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) To fix this, make a copy of the loop variable `i` before passing it to the task:

```
SemaphoreSlim maxThreadSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2); //Max 2 tasks at a time.

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)                     //loop through 5 tasks to be assigned
{
    maxThreadSemaphore.Wait();                  //Wait for the queue

    Console.WriteLine("Assigning work {0} ", i);
    int copy = i; // <----- Make a copy here.

    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                DoWork(copy.ToString());                   // assign tasks
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
        )
        .ContinueWith(
            (task) => maxThreadSemaphore.Release()  // step out of the queue
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the solution and for the link on modified closures

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that before the `Task` is started the loop has allready run through and is starting the next `Task`.

As @Matthew Watson recommended you should use `Parallel.For`.

---

Just out of interest this would solve your problem:

```
static void LaunchTaskPool()
{
    SemaphoreSlim maxThreadSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2); //Max 2 tasks at a time.

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)                     //loop through 5 tasks to be assigned
    {
        maxThreadSemaphore.Wait();                  //Wait for the queue

        Console.WriteLine("Assigning work {0} ", i);

        StartThead(i, maxThreadSemaphore);
    }
}

static void StartThead(int i, SemaphoreSlim maxThreadSemaphore)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => DoWork(i.ToString()),
        TaskCreationOptions.None
    ).ContinueWith((task) => maxThreadSemaphore.Release());
}

static void DoWork(string workname)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine("--work {0} starts", workname);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("--work  {0} finishes", workname);
}
```