# Best way to handle exception in multi task to call WCF operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have implemented a service name `ExamClient` which have two operations one is `Ping` which return a basic `string` which mean service is available and one is `FindStudy` which search in DB it may take a long to be proceeded.

In the other side I have several endpoints of `ExamClient` I wand to run `FindStudy` per end point by task so in a `Dispatcher` I have something like this:

```
public FindStudies_DTO_OUT FindStudies(FindStudies_DTO_IN findStudies_DTO_IN)
{
    List<Study_C> ret = new List<Study_C>(); 
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var sp in Cluster)
    {
        string serviceAddress = sp.GetLibraryAddress(ServiceLibrary_C.PCM) + "/Exam.svc";
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ExamClient examClient = new ExamClient(serviceAddress.GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress), Token);
            var ping = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                examClient.Ping();
            }); 
            if (!ping.Wait(examClient.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout))
            {
                Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Warning, "Timeout on FindStudies for:{0}, address:{1}", sp.Name, serviceAddress);
                return new List<Study_C>(); // if return null then need to manage it on ret.AddRange(t.Result);
            }  
            return (examClient.FindStudies(findStudies_DTO_IN).Studies.Select(x =>
            {
                x.StudyInstanceUID = string.Format("{0}|{1}", sp.Name, x.StudyInstanceUID);
                x.InstitutionName = sp.Name;
                return x;
            }));
        });
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            lock (ret)
            {
                ret.AddRange(t.Result);
            }
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "FindStudies failed for :{0}, address:{1}, EXP:{2}", sp.Name, serviceAddress, t.Exception.ToString());
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        tasks.Add(task);
    } 
    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
    catch (AggregateException aggEx)
    {
        foreach (Exception exp in aggEx.InnerExceptions)
        {
            Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "Error while FindStudies EXP:{0}", exp.ToString());
        }
    }

    return new FindStudies_DTO_OUT(ret.Sort(findStudies_DTO_IN.SortColumnName, findStudies_DTO_IN.SortOrderBy));
}
```

First I have to run `Ping` per end point to know connection is established
after that `FindStudy`.

if there are three end pints in `Cluster` six task be run in parallel mode, 3 for `Ping` and 3 for `FindStudy`.

I think something is wrong with my code to handle exception nice...
So what is the best way to implement this scenario ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Wait()` inside your tasks just to access the timeout logic.... see answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)

Comment: Look at the comments as well regarding the cancellation token stuff. That's really important!

Comment: I think I should wait because open time out is 3 seconds if an endpoint is available `Ping` get respond within 3 seconds.

Comment: No, using `Wait()` is really bad practise and can lead to deadlocks. The correct way to cancel tasks is through cancellation tokens, which also have timeouts on them. `Ping()` may accept a cancellation token as an argument.

Comment: No `Ping()` is an operation of my service, in my opinion `Ping()` must get respond in less than 3 seconds .

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me. You are fine having your 3 second timeout, but your implementation is flawed.

Comment: upvote I think so it is flawed but what is best implementation, I am newbie in TPL.

Answer (score 1):

Let me throw my answer to simplify and remove unnecessary code block. And bit of explanation along the code.

```
public FindStudies_DTO_OUT FindStudies(FindStudies_DTO_IN findStudies_DTO_IN)
{
    // Thread-safe collection
    var ret = new ConcurrentBag<Study_C>()

    // Loop cluster list and process each item in parallel and wait all process to finish. This handle the parallism better than task run
    Parallel.Foreach(Cluster, (sp) =>
    {
        var serviceAddress = sp.GetLibraryAddress(ServiceLibrary_C.PCM) + "/Exam.svc";

        ExamClient examClient = new ExamClient(serviceAddress.GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress), Token);

        try
        {
            examClient.Ping();              
            // declare result variable type outside try catch to be visible below               
            var result = examClient.FindStudies(findStudies_DTO_IN);
        }
        catch(TimeoutException timeoutEx)
        {
            // abort examclient to dispose channel properly
            Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Warning, "Timeout on FindStudies for:{0}, address:{1}", sp.Name, serviceAddress);
        }
        catch(FaultException fault)
        {
            Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "FindStudies failed for :{0}, address:{1}, EXP:{2}", sp.Name, serviceAddress, fault.Exception.ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // anything else
        }
        // add exception type as needed for proper logging

        // use inverted if to reduce nested condition
        if( result == null )
            return null;

        var study_c = result.Studies.Select(x =>
        {
            x.StudyInstanceUID = string.Format("{0}|{1}", sp.Name, x.StudyInstanceUID);
            x.InstitutionName = sp.Name;
            return x;
        }));

        // Thread-safe collection
        ret.AddRange(study_c);      
    });

    // for sorting i guess concurrentBag has orderby; if not working convert to list
    return new FindStudies_DTO_OUT(ret.Sort(findStudies_DTO_IN.SortColumnName, findStudies_DTO_IN.SortOrderBy));
}
```

**Note :** Code haven't tested but the gist is there. Also I feels like task.run inside task.run is bad idea can't remember which article I read it (probably from Stephen Cleary not sure).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I think this is not proper solution because if an endpoint is not available ,`Ping` take long to get response equal `receivetimeout` .

Comment: If im not mistaken, if endpoint is not available it immediately throw an exception.

Comment: No you are mistake, it is tested for this reason I have to run a task into another task.