# Time out reversal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, task

I need to integrate an API into my development with a specific scenario called "Time Out Reversal" (TOR)

This means, succintly, to comply with the following requirements:

- Initiate a request by invoking an endpoint
- If a response is not received within a defined time out
- start a reversal request by invoking another endpoint

While the requirements seems very clear to me, I really haven't found a way to implement it by using tasks.

For example, I know how to delay a task but I dont really know how to set a timeout in seconds for a started task

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily implement a timeout like so:

```
public async Task TimoutReversal() {
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    try {
        //assumes HttpClient
        Client.Timeout = timeout;
        await Client.GetAsync(firstEndpoint);
    } catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
        await Client.DeleteAsync(secondEndpoint);
    }
}

//or

public async Task TimoutReversal() {
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    var firstTask = Client.GetAsync(firstEndpoint);
    if (await Task.WhenAny(firstTask, Task.Delay(timeout)) == firstTask) {
        //success
    }else {
        //failure
        await Client.DeleteAsync(secondEndpoint);
    }
}
```

Also see protected answer here on SO: [Task with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)

Another option is to pass the `Token` from a `CancellationTokenSource` created from a `TimeSpan` to the `HttpClient` calls.