# Cancel a Task if it hasnt completed in 5 seconds

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

I've an asynchronous method where I'm running a void-return type method in a Task and I want that method to be cancelled in X time (let's say 5 seconds) if it hasn't completed by then.

I found two similar threads:
[Cancel long running Task after 5 seconds when not finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116824/cancel-long-running-task-after-5-seconds-when-not-finished)
[Asynchronously wait for Task<T> to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)
but I don't manage to get the cancellation to work using these.

This is what I've so far:

```
 using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000))
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    CandySystem.QueryCandies(rowOrderByIndex, columnOrderByIndex,
                        orderByDescending);
                }, cts.Token);
            }
```

I expect method "QueryCandies" to cancel after running for 5 seconds.
Could someone provide me "for dummies" explanation what's going wrong here?

Comment: To somewhat oversimplify, the cancellation token is checked before the task is started, and if it is cancelled then the task won't even be started - otherwise, the code run by the task will need to check a cancellation token itself in order to cancel. (Normally you'd pass the same cancellation token to your task code and check it at some point or points.) The `Task` class itself will NOT attempt to cancel a task once its been started!

Comment: @MatthewWatson Ahh silly me. I got it working now, thanks!