# How to set timeout in Refit library

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, refit

I am using Refit library in my Xamarin App, I want to set 10 seconds timeout for the request. Is there any way to do this in refit?

Interface:

```
interface IDevice
{
  [Get("/app/device/{id}")]
  Task<Device> GetDevice(string id, [Header("Authorization")] string authorization);
}
```

Invoking the API

```
var device = RestService.For<IDevice>("http://localhost");              
var dev = await device.GetDevice("15e2a691-06df-4741-b26e-87e1eecc6bd7", "Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I finally found a way of setting the timeout for a request in Refit. I used `CancelationToken`. Here is the modified code after adding `CancelationToken`

Interface:

```
interface IDevice
{
  [Get("/app/device/{id}")]
  Task<Device> GetDevice(string id, [Header("Authorization")] string authorization, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Invoking the API:

```
var device = RestService.For<IDevice>("http://localhost");    
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
tokenSource.CancelAfter(10000); // 10000 ms
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;          
var dev = await device.GetDevice("15e2a691-06df-4741-b26e-87e1eecc6bd7", "Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN", token);
```

It works properly for me. I don't know whether it is the proper way or not. If it is a wrong, kindly suggest the correct way.

Comment: I've seen this a couple times, but it's not in the Refit documentation.  Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: I do not know if is there any documentation present for this. I found this code by looking into the auto-suggestion and method signature

Comment: Not documentation, but found suggestive code:  https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/637182e90e75d433d0aa02ad28f0c62b11a4592a/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs#L853  The code also implies a default cancellation token that is used if supplied, and if not supplied the function parameter supplied cancellation token is used.

Comment: https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/a9cda050af41e8b135c4d0c2fe191e32175702a8/Refit/RestMethodInfo.cs#L126

Answer (score 33):

The accepted answer is the correct way to enforce a timeout for a single request, but if you want to have a single consistent timeout value for all requests, you can pass a preconfigured `HttpClient` with its `Timeout` property set:

```
var api = RestService.For<IDevice>(new HttpClient 
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost"),
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
});
```

Here is an [example project](https://github.com/bennor/RefitGlobalTimeout).

Comment: It works for me. Which part doesn't work? Setting a timeout this way has nothing to do with Refit -- it's just a standard `HttpClient` thing.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Added a link to an example project to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution: One of the [tests](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/0baec2ea6f462264696fe476a88dfc267b527ad7/Refit.Tests/RestService.cs) in Refit uses this method. Add [System.Reactive.Linq](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) in nuget.
Then in the interface specification:

```
interface IDevice
{
    [Get("/app/device/{id}")]
    IObservable<Device> GetDevice(string id, [Header("Authorization")] string authorization);
}
```

And in the API:

```
try
{
  await device.GetDevice("your_parameters_here").Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
catch(System.TimeoutException e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Timeout: " + e.Message);
}
```

---

+1 solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22078975/9963147):

Create an extension method for your tasks:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<TResult> TimeoutAfter<TResult>(this Task<TResult> task, TimeSpan timeout)
    {

        using (var timeoutCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {

            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout, timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token));
            if (completedTask == task)
            {
                timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                return await task;  // Very important in order to propagate exceptions
            }
            else
            {
                throw new TimeoutException("The operation has timed out.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Interface can be left using `Task<Device>` return value. In the API:

```
try
{
  await _server.ListGasLines().TimeoutAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}
catch(System.TimeoutException e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Timeout: " + e.Message);
}
```