# asp.net core: how to set the requesttimeout for a single action/route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In asp.net core, how can you set the `requesttimeout` for a single action?

I know I can set the webconfig:
    [image]

but this is global, and I want a longer timeout on only one action.

Answer (score 0):

You may implement timeout yourself in controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoNotHang()
{
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    var operation = LongOperationAsync(); // no "await" here!

    if (await Task.WhenAny(operation, Task.Delay(timeout)) == operation)
    {
        var result = await operation; // obtain result (if needed)
        return Ok(result == null ? "Null" : "Not null");
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok("Timed out (but still working, not cancelled)");
    }
}
```

See [Asynchronously wait for Task<T> to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/) for more details on await-ing with timeout, including cancellation of "other" task when one completes.