# Check time taken by a thread inside Parallel.Foreach and exit if it is taking more time

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have code with Parallel.Foreach which is processing files and doing some operation on each file in parallel.

```
Parallel.ForEach(lstFiles, file=>
{
 // Doing some operation on file
 // Skip file and move to next if it is taking too long
});
```

I want to skip a file and move to next file **(but don't want to exit the Parallel.Foreach)** if a particular file is taking too long (say 2 mins). Is there any way in Parallel.Foreach to check the time taken by thread to process a single file.

Thanks

Comment: You could await a task inside the foreach block and wait for the task with WhenAny like is shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout.

Comment: `I want to skip a file and move to next file` - This statment is confusing. `Parallel.ForEach` is processing all files in the list in paralell, not 1 at a time. If you decide to just stop processing a particular file, that's all you need to do. The others will keep going concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you don't use `Parallel.ForEach` and instead use Mirosoft's extremely more powerful Reactive Framework. Then you can do this:

```
var query =
    from file in lstFiles.ToObservable()
    from result in Observable.Amb(
        Observable.Start(() => SomeOperation(file)).Select(_ => true),
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0)).Select(_ => false))
    select new { file, result };

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            /* do something with each `new { file, result }`
               as they arrive. */
        }, ex =>
        {
            /* do something if an error is encountered */
            /* (stops processing on first error) */
        }, () =>
        {
            /* do something if they have all finished successfully */
        })
```

This is all done in parallel. The `Observable.Amb` operator starts the two observables defined in its argument list and takes the value from which ever of the two produces a value first - if it's the `Start` observable it has processed your file and if it's the `Timer` observable then `2.0` minutes has elapsed without a result from the file.

If you want to stop the processing when it is half-way through then just call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Use NuGet "System.Reactive" to get the bits.

---

The query in lambda form as per request in comments:

```
var query =
    lstFiles
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(
            file =>
                Observable.Amb(
                    Observable.Start(() => SomeOperation(file)).Select(_ => true),
                    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0)).Select(_ => false)),
            (file, result) => new { file, result });
```

Comment: can you please also add your linq query"var query =
    from file in lstFiles.ToObservable()" in Lambda form ?

Comment: @Gerry - I've added the lambda form for the query.

Comment: Thank you so much @Enigmativity.

Comment: Will Amb process the files in parallel (like parallel.foreach) or i need to do it explicitly ?

Comment: @Gerry - `.Amb` starts both of the observables passed to it and returns the first one to produce a value. It does each in parallel. But it's the `.SelectMany` that causes each of the `lstFiles` to be processed in parallel. It's all done for you.

Comment: ok, So i Can replace my Parallel.Foreach completely with Rx. 
I was thinking to merge both Parallel.Foreach and Rx to achieve parallel processing.

Comment: @Gerry - No, don't mix them. Rx can do all of the parallel work for you. And it's fair more powerful than the `Parallel` operations.

Comment: OK @Enigmativity, Thanks for valuable suggestion

Comment: @Gerry - "far" more powerful I meant.