# Set a timeout on a redirect chain

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, timeout

I am trying to trace a chain of redirects (for an online ad pixel) programmatically, but with a timeout of 2 seconds (in other words, if the redirect chain takes more than 2 seconds to resolve, I want it to abort and return null).

My code is (more or less) running synchronously, so I had to do some acrobatics to do what I wanted, but functionally speaking, it seems to work... except for the timeout part.

I have some asynchronous helpers like so:

```
    public static async Task<TResult> TimeoutAfter<TResult>(this Task<TResult> task, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        using (var timeoutCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout, timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token));
            if (completedTask != task)
            {
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
            timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            return await task; 
        }
    }

    public static T ToSynchronousResult<T>(this Task<T> task)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () => await task).Result;
    }
```

The `TimeoutAfter()` helper method was adapted from the SO article that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout).  In my service I have a method that resembles this:

```
    public string GetFinalUrl(string url)
    {
        string finalUrl;

        try
        {
            finalUrl = FollowDestinationUrl(url).TimeoutAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).ToSynchronousResult();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            finalUrl = null;
        }

        return finalUrl;
    }

    private async Task<string> FollowDestinationUrl(string url)
    {
        var request = _webRequestFactory.CreateGet(url);
        var payload = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        return payload.ResponseUri.ToString();
    }
```

The `_webRequestFactory` here returns an HttpWebRequest abstraction that was written as an `IHttpRequest`.

In my success case unit test (response under 2 seconds), I get back the result I expect:

```
    private class TestWebResponse : WebResponse
    {
        public override Uri ResponseUri => new Uri("https://www.mytest.com/responseIsGood");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RedirectUriUnderTimeout()
    {
        //arrange
        var service = GetService();
        A.CallTo(() => _httpRequest.GetResponseAsync()).ReturnsLazily(() => new TestWebResponse());
        A.CallTo(() => _httpRequest.GetResponseString())
            .ReturnsLazily(() => VALID_REQUEST_PAYLOAD);

        //act
        var url = service.GetFinalUrl("https://someplace.com/testurl");

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(url);
    }
```

...however, when I try to implement a delay to verify the timeout is working correctly, it's not aborting as I would expect:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void RedirectUriUnderTimeout()
    {
        //arrange
        var service = GetService();
        A.CallTo(() => _httpRequest.GetResponseAsync()).ReturnsLazily(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            return new TestWebResponse();
        });
        A.CallTo(() => _httpRequest.GetResponseString())
            .ReturnsLazily(() => VALID_REQUEST_PAYLOAD);

        //act
        var url = service.GetFinalUrl("https://someplace.com/testurl");

        //assert
        Assert.IsNull(url);
    }
```

It seems like it waits for the full three seconds, before returning the `TestWebResponse` that has a non-null `ResponseUri`.

I don't know if there's something fundamentally wrong with my implementation, or wrong with my test, but obviously I'm blocking an async call in a way I'm not expecting to.

Can someone help me identify what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like I was way overthinking it.  @Stormcloak clued me in that what I was doing wasn't going to work, so I started looking at alternatives, and I realized that while the async/ await pattern weren't appropriate here, the TPL library still came in handy.

I changed my `FinalDestinationUrl` method to synchronous like so:

```
private string FollowDestinationUrl(string url)
    {
        var request = _webRequestFactory.CreateGet(url);
        var payload = request.GetResponse();
        return payload.ResponseUri.ToString();
    }
```

then I called it like so:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => FollowDestinationUrl(destinationUrl));
finalUrl = task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)) ? task.Result : null;
```

Then I changed my unit test to resemble:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RedirectUriUnderTimeout()
{
    //arrange
    var service = GetService();
    A.CallTo(() => _httpRequest.GetResponse()).ReturnsLazily(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        return new TestWebResponse();
    });
    A.CallTo(() => _httpRequest.GetResponseString())
        .ReturnsLazily(() => VALID_REQUEST_PAYLOAD);

    //act
    var url = service.GetFinalUrl("https://someplace.com/testurl");

    //assert
    Assert.IsNull(url);
}
```

The test passed.  All is well in the world.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static T ToSynchronousResult<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    return Task.Run(async () => await task).Result;
}
```

This part causes to get thread blocked.As you mentioned the method `ToSynchronousResult`, it will block the thread until task result returned. You should follow *"async all the way"* rule and you should use `await`. It is only way to apply `async` efficiently.

```
public async Task<string> GetFinalUrl(string url)
{
    string finalUrl;

    try
    {
        finalUrl = await FollowDestinationUrl(url).TimeoutAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        finalUrl = null;
    }

    return finalUrl;
}
```

Comment: I can't use async all the way; I'd have to change half the code base to do it.  Is there an alternative?

Comment: If you can't use async all the way, how would you expect to be executed your code non-blocked/async for all the way?

Comment: I was hoping for an "interrupt" effect, as it were... i.e., spend a maximum of two seconds trying then bail.  In other words, abort from outside the process flow.  I know it's possible to do with async, so I tried to get around the problem.

Comment: As a further question, wouldn't the thrown exception "unblock" the thread?  I'd imagine it should return immediately when that happens, but I acknowledge that my understanding could be flawed.