# The c # task does not wait for the delay timer

Tags: async-await, task

I am using a waiting task delay. I want to understand the problem by giving an example:

```
private async void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        label1.Text = "1";
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        label1.Text = "2";
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
```

Timer internal: 1000 Problem : Always writes 1 and 2 to the label.Can not wait

When I write the above code to the timer, it always starts and nonsense. I want to sleep without freezing the form. how can I do that?

Comment: you should use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with ` Thread.Sleep();` in it.

Comment: Also, as Timer interval is 1000 so you have to stop timer out of `Task.Factory.StartNew()` block

Comment: could you give an example :)

Comment: @Amogh, I agree that the timer must be stopped or have an interval bigger than 15000 but, in what `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Thread.Sleep` would help here?

Comment: @PauloMorgado A bit late to reply, but in `Task.Factory.StartNew` we can call `label1.Invoke()` to set text to label on UI thread. Anyways your answer is also perfect.

Comment: In that case, you should be using `IProgress`\`Progress<T>` instead of `Control.Invoke`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the timer interval?

Try this:

```
private volatile int running;

private async void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.running != 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.running, 1);

    await Task.Delay(5000);
    label1.Text = "1";
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    label1.Text = "2";
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.running, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not exactly sure why that would not work but there could be a number of reasons.  You could be delaying the wrong thread/task(I'v ran into this issue in Java)?  Could I ask if this code works inplace so we can get more information on the issue?  If this works then it should confirm that the problem is a task or thread issue.  You many need to modify this slightly and add breakpoints as needed.

```
        DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime firstDelay = begin.AddSeconds(5);
        DateTime secondDelay = begin.AddSeconds(10);
        DateTime thirdDelay = begin.AddSeconds(15);
        while (begin <= firstDelay)
        {
            begin = DateTime.Now;
        }
        label1.text = "1";
        while (begin <= secondDelay)
        {
            begin = DateTime.Now;                
        }
        label1.text = "2";
        while (begin <= thirdDelay)
        {
            begin = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

Comment: I could recommend looking into this page:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout                the first comment on the best answer explains why task.delay is an issue

Comment: if(wait==0)
            {
                wait = 1;
                label1.Text = "1";
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                label1.Text = "2";
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                wait = 2;
             
            }
            if(wait==2)
            { wait = 0;
            }

I did something like that but I need more stability :(

Comment: You could also try the Thread.Sleep method  :
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

Comment: the form need not be frozen. I just want to work like thread.sleep. However, the Await task always writes 1 and 2 to Label1.

output: unfortunately unexpected series 1 and 2 :( why do not I understand why? :(