# Handle a long download time

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I sent a request to server using **HttpClient**, how can I limit the boot time, for example, 30 seconds?

Here is my method:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    return await client.SendAsync(request);
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw new HttpRequestException();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw new HttpRequestException();
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw new HttpRequestException();
            }
        }
```

How can i limit download time?

Comment: Might be you are looking like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11191070/7124761

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronously wait for Task<T> to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
int timeout = 1000;
var task = SomeOperationAsync();
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task) {
    // task completed within timeout
} else { 
    // timeout logic
}
```