# How to get unfinished tasks when Task.WaitAll times out?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

When waiting synchronously an *array of tasks* to complete with the `Task.WaitAll` method, it is possible to specify a *timeout* in milliseconds. When the timeout is reached `WaitAll` stops waiting and returns `false`.

I would like to know if there is a way **to get a sublist of the tasks that did not reach completion after the timeout.**

Comment: `tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCompleted)`? Note that there is always an inherent race condition between a timeout and checking the results of the timeout, so `WaitAll` having dedicated code to return the tasks that did not complete would not be better than checking it after the fact.

Comment: look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) in the comments, when `Task.WaitAll` returns `false` after the timeout we can filter for the completed tasks.

Example:

```
var tasks = new task[] 
{
    Task.Run(someMethod),
    Task.Run(someMethod1),
    Task.Run(someMethod2),
    Task.Run(someMethod3),
};

bool allTasksAreCompleted = Task.WaitAll(tasks, 10000);

if (!allTasksAreCompleted)
{
    var incompleteTasks = tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCompleted);
}
```

If `Task.WaitAll` times out, we will get the incomplete tasks in the `incompleteTasks` variable.