# Parallel start of several tasks, each of which has its own timeout

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have several similar tasks, each of which is limited to a timeout, i.e. must be completed faster than the specified time or return an empty result. The main purpose of these tasks is receiving a response from the server with a timeout limit.
An example of such task is below:

```
       public async Task<List<Data>> GetDataWithTimeoutAsync(InputData data, int timeout)
        {   
            List<Data> resultData = new List<Data>;
            await Task.WhenAny(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    resultData.Add(SomeWork(data));
                }),
                Task.Delay(timeout));

            return resultData;
        }
```

Each of these tasks works correctly separately.

But I want to run some of such tasks in parallel. For this, I use the following code.

```
        public async Task<List<List<Data>>> GetAllDataAsync()
        {
            var resultTasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task<List<Data>>>();

            var firtsTask = GetDataWithTimeoutAsync(firstInputData, firtsTimeout);
            var secondTask = GetDataWithTimeoutAsync(secondInputData, secondTimeout);
            var thirdTask = GetDataWithTimeoutAsync(thirdInputData, thirdTimeout);

            resultTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => firtsTask));
            resultTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => secondTask));
            resultTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => thirdTask));

            await Task.WhenAll(resultTasks);

            var result = resultTasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToList();

            return result;

        }
```

But this code works incorrectly if different timeouts are set for nested tasks. In this case all of tasks are completed after the smallest of the timeouts.

How i can run some tasks in parallel with WhenAll if each of task is a result of WhenAny?

Comment: You should not do a Task.Run at `resultTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => firtsTask));
` since you already start a task inside `GetDataWithTimeoutAsync`. Just do `resultTasks.Add(firtsTask));`

Comment: @Peter Bons I tried to do this way. This did not lead to a result.

Comment: @AndreyDengin it was not even necessary to create an answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout

Comment: @AndreyDengin maybe it is option to use `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter` and then do actual work if token is not cancelled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, so I wrote something similar. I can't reproduce your results. In my case the `WhenAll` with different timeouts works as expected. It completes when the longest running task is completed, which is the second one (200 msec).

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var task1 = GetDataAsync(100).WithTimeout(50);  // Should timeout after 50 msec
    var task2 = GetDataAsync(200).WithTimeout(300); // Should complete after 200 msec
    var task3 = GetDataAsync(300).WithTimeout(100); // Should timeout after 100 msec
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3); // Wait for all
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Results: {String.Join(", ", results)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} msec");
}

private static async Task<int> GetDataAsync(int input) // the input is used as delay
{
    await Task.Delay(input);
    return input;
}

public static Task<T> WithTimeout<T>(this Task<T> task, int timeout)
{
    var delayTask = Task.Delay(timeout).ContinueWith(_ => default(T),
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    return Task.WhenAny(task, delayTask).Unwrap();
}
```

Output:

```
Results: 0, 200, 0
Elapsed: 211 msec
```