# In C#, can I start a background operation, kill it and get its stack trace?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, timeout, stack-trace

In my C# application (unit test, actually) I want to be able to launch an operation and set a timeout. If the timeout elapses and my operation has not terminated, I want to:

1. Throw an exception.
2. Include a stack trace of the thread running the operation.
3. If reasonably convenient, cancel the operation.

I can accomplish point #1 using the method described in this answer by Lawrence Johnston: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22078975/8557153

How can I accomplish point 2? I have a reference to a Task, but I know that Task objects do not have stack traces per se. A Task just a data structure of some kind. Only threads have stack traces. But is there any way to get a stack trace from the thread running the task, if any? Or will I need to completely rewrite the body of my task to make this possible?

Point 3 is optional. It is acceptable to have the task continue unawaited in the background, but it would be nice to abort it.

Comment: This is not possible in general. Consider a task that is awaiting `Task.Delay()`: In that case, a `Timer` will have been created to continue after the delay, and there will be no code running for which to obtain a stack trace. The same goes for many other cases, such as awaiting I/O - [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cancellation tokens. It will do all 3 things you want:

1. When tasks are cancelled, they throw a `TaskCancelledException`.
2. The exception will have a stack trace.
3. The task will be cancelled.

You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation), but here's a quick example:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

//start a task
var task = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), tokenSource.Token);

//cancel the task
tokenSource.Cancel();

try {
    //once you await it, you will see the exception
    await task;
} catch (TaskCanceledException e) {
    //inspect e.StackTrace
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I assume that for this to work, I need to rewrite the code that runs in the task to call `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` regularly (like in the example in the article you linked)?

Comment: Yes, and pass the token to any async methods that you call.