# Set maximum runtime of a method

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

If I have a method where I want to perform some (potentially) long-running function and I want to put a limit on its execution time, I've been using this pattern (please pardon any errors in the code, typed by hand, not in an IDE, this is a simplification of a larger piece of code).

```
public string GetHello()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => 
    {
        // do something long running
        return "Hello";
    });

    bool success = task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

    if (success)
    {
        return task.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("Timed out.");
    }
}
```

If I want to use the `GetHello` method in an async capacity, i.e. `public async Task<string> GetHello()`, how would I do this while hopefully preserving a similar pattern?  I have the following, but I get compiler warnings about `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously` as expected.

```
public async Task<string> GetHello()
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        // await something long running
        return "Hello";
    });

    bool success = task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

    if (success)
    {
        return task.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("Timed out.");
    }
}
```

I just don't know how to change this or where I would put await in order for this to work as expected.

Comment: You can add a `CancellationTokenSource`. Read the docs [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1) :: CancellationTokenSource(Int32) 
Initializes a new instance of the CancellationTokenSource class that will be canceled after the specified delay in milliseconds.

Comment: I know how CancellationTokenSource works - how is that relevant to answering my question?

Comment: Guru Stron implemented the `CancellationTokenSource` as I mentioned. That is how it is relevant

Comment: Throwing that `TimeoutException` won't necessarily stop the `task` from continuing to run. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @Barns pointing me to the docs isn't providing an answer, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks @John Wu for pointing that out, I will make sure that's addressed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronously wait for `Task<T>` to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11191070/2791540)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine using `CancellationToken` and awaitable `Task.WhenAny` to achieve desired behavior:

```
public async Task<string> GetHello()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // await something long running and pass/use cts.Token here too
        return "Hello";
    }, cts.Token);

    var delay = Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);

    var finishedFirst = await Task.WhenAny(task, delay);
    cts.Cancel();
    if (finishedFirst == task)
    {
        return task.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("Timed out.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably more important is that the async method checks the token and aborts if it's been cancelled. Otherwise the long running work may still run *long* after the timeout exception is thrown

Comment: So add ```cts.Cancel()``` in the ```else``` block?

Comment: @joelc not in the `else` block, to the `await something long running`.