# Async long running process

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a question about a scenario I need to code.  I have a process that will send a request file via SFTP and then I will need to wait for a response file to be created on the ftp server before I download and continue my processing.  The response file could take anywhere between 1min to 60mins to appear.  If I await this process, is there a way that I can say, give up after 60 mins?
C#

Comment: You could add an CancelationToken with a duration of 60Minutes

Comment: How are you sending the request file via SFTP? Is the send operation cancellable?

Comment: ^^ Also, it would be interesting how you track and wait for the "response file" to appear. Best would be to post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CancellationTokenSource

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource =
    new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));
```

Wrap the code in a try/catch and watch for `TaskCanceledException`

Also, check out [Asynchronously wait for Task to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)